# updating of Image Thumbnails using AsyncTask for Android ListView not coming proper

Tags: android, image, performance, listview, android-asynctask

I am getting a big response from the server with data and image url. I need to display them on the List View. Images should be like thumbnails. To make it proper i have customized my Adapter and getting the images using Async Task. Here is my Adapter and Asynctask Code:

```
   public class TalkofTownAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Context context = null;
    ImageView thumb_image = null;
    private ProgressDialog progressbar = null;

    ArrayList<String> items;
    ArrayList<String> thumb_url;
     public TalkofTownAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<String> thumb) 
     {
         this.context = c;
         this.items = list;
         this.thumb_url = thumb;
         progressbar = new ProgressDialog(c);
         Log.d("Testing", "talk of town adapter constructor   "+items.size());
         inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talkoftown, null);
            Log.d("Testing", "before creating holder object");
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
            holder.duration = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image_playlist);
            Log.d("Testing", "image view created ::::::::   ");
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Log.d("Testing", "text:::   "+items.get(position));
        holder.headlineView.setText(items.get(position));
        Log.d("Testing", "settting the text   ");
        holder.duration.setText("22/09/1987");

        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            Log.d("Testing", "getting the image  "+thumb_url.get(position));
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(thumb_url.get(position));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView duration;
        ImageView imageView;
    }


    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            Log.d("Testing", "image loaded  "+myBitmap);
//          myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 50, Config.ARGB_8888);
            myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap,(int)(myBitmap.getWidth()), (int)(myBitmap.getHeight()), true);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Testing", "exception is getting the image "+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void startProgress()
    {
        progressbar.setMessage("Please wait");
        progressbar.show();
    }

    public void stopProgress()
    {
        progressbar.dismiss();
    }

    class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        // Actual download method, run in the task thread
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            return getBitmapFromURL(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.rihanna));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Now the thumbnails are showing with the default image and then changing with downloaded images. But if i am scrolling down the list view, images are keep on changing and coming duplicates of those that appeared in the rows above that were already scrolled up. So i mean to say here, the images are coming on proper order for the corresponding rows. I know there are lots of tutorials and QA here also. But i have tried lots of solutions and it did not work properly.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Change your if condition like `if(thumb_url.get(position) !=null)`

Comment: You may want to see my own answer to my question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44216331/image-thumbnails-not-setting-correctly/44528936#44528936

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with you if condition. Just remove the if condition `if (holder.imageView != null) {` the problem is each and everytime getView will check for your view is null or not and based on that it will execute and inflate the image.

Change your if condition like

```
    if(thumb_url.get(position) !=null)
    {
      Log.d("Testing", "getting the image  "+thumb_url.get(position));
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(thumb_url.get(position));
    }
```

Comment: It is not working. Still the issue is present. Suppose for the first row, thumbnails are coming with 4 images. First the default image, then some other images which are from server. And it is keep on changing with time or while scrolling. I am really clueless with this behavior.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?